# Given $c_{n+1} = \frac 1 2 (\sqrt{c_n} + \frac 1 {\sqrt{c_n}})$, compute $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given real number $C > 1$, let
$$
c_1 = C \\
c_{n+1} = \frac 1 2 (\sqrt{c_n} + \frac 1 {\sqrt{c_n}})
$$

How to compute
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n 
$$

---

I have proved that the limit does exist.

Let $x = C-1$, then
$$
c_{n+1} < c_{n+1}^2 = \frac 1 4(c_n + 2 + \frac 1 {c_n}) < 1 + \frac 1 4(c_n - 1)
$$
So
$$
c_{n+1} < 1 + \frac 1 {4^n}x \leq \max (x, 1) (1 + \frac 1 {4^n})
$$

Since it's clear that $\lim_{n \to \inf}[ (1 + \frac 1 2)(1 + \frac 1 {2^2}) \dots (1 + \frac 1 {2^n})]$ converges and $x$ would become less than one after finite iterations so
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n
$$
exists.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this product has a nice closed form?